# How to hide Zend Element Label using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework

Hi i have a script that hides and show which select element will be render depends on the value of a select dropdown.

```
function testOnClick(){ 
  var e = document.getElementById("role");

  var selectValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  alert(selectValue);
  if(selectValue == 1)
  {       
     // $("#item").toggle();
      $("#sub_unit").show();
      $("#sub_unit_dropdown").hide();
      $('#sub_unit_dropdown').parent().children().hide()    
    }
  else
  {
      $("#sub_unit").hide();
      $('#sub_unit').parent().children().hide()
      $("#sub_unit_dropdown").show();
      }
```

}

Here is the zend elements

```
 $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'role',
                'id'   => 'role',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Role',              
                'empty_option' => '(Please select)',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '1' => 'Manager',
                    '2' => 'Employee',
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'status',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Status',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '1' => 'Active',
                    '2' => 'Inactive',
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'sub_unit',
            'id'   => 'sub_unit',               
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Sub Unit / Team',
                'value_options' => $this->getOptionsForSubUnit(),
                'description' => 'Hold down the control (ctrl) button to select multiple options',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'size'     => 12,
            ),
        ));

          $this->add(array(
            'name'       => 'sub_unit_dropdown',
            'id'        => 'sub_unit_dropdown',
            'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options'    => array(
                'label' => 'Sub Unit / Team',
                'value_options' => $this->getOptionsForSubUnit(),
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'size'     => 12,
                'class' => 'input-medium'
            ),
        ));
```

It works correctly, it hides and show which select element will be hide or show but the problem is the label of the hide select element is still visible.
How can I hide it together with the select element need to be hide?.

TIA

Comment: share your html code and let us know which label you want hide ??

Comment: They are zend elements

these are the zend elements

I edited my question

Comment: So you want to hide/ show 'Sub Unit / Team'  labels. Am i right ??

Comment: You can try with ``$("#sub_unit").prev('label').hide()`` . I am assuming that ``label``  tag coming just before input element.  Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please test if this works,

```
$this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'sub_unit_dropdown',
        'id'        => 'sub_unit_dropdown',
        'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'options'    => array(
            'label' => 'Sub Unit / Team',
            'label_attributes' => array('class' => 'hidethelabel'),
            'value_options' => $this->getOptionsForSubUnit(),
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'size'     => 12,
            'class' => 'input-medium'
        ),
    ));
```

basically I thought you can add a class or an id

> 'label_attributes' => array('class' => 'hidethelabel')

and use that id/class inside your script to hide the label.

Just an idea.

Comment: Hi, Thanks it works perfectly but now my problem is the description, I tried also giving it class attribute but it doesn't work.

Comment: try searching how to add attribute on description element created by zend form and you should find the answer. If not post another questions and we will give it a go